# Change of variables in a wave PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, chain-rule, wave-equation, change-of-variable

The textbooks says that 
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + c \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$
can be transformed into 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x'} = 0$$
by introducing a new variable $x' = x - c t$.

It's embarrassing, but I can't do it. It seemed logical to me at first glance to employ a chain rule here like $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}$, but obviously something else has to be done.

Comment: Remember that $x'$ is function of multiple variables. You are using the one variable version of chain rule, but you need to use its multivariable counterpart.

Comment: You need to calculate $\partial u/\partial t$, too. To do this, you'll need to use the chain rule (as the first comment indicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understanding the two PDEs**

In the first equation you have $u(x,t)$ so $\partial u/\partial t$ means differentiate $t$ and hold $x$ constant. In the second equation we hold $x'$ constant, when differentiating with respect to $t$.

**Making the change of variables**

I will now use a notation that my undergraduate physics professor Dr. Buchholtz used in his statistical mechanics course, in which a subscript is used to denote which variable is being held constant when differentiating.

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{x}&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{x'}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\left(\frac{\partial x'}{\partial t}\right)_{x}\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{x'}-c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\\
\end{align*}

Using the following that you were able to determine

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{t}&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}\right)_{t}\\
\end{align*}

will allow you to properly make the change of variables and obtain the result from the book.

I hope this helps.